# Decode user input with special characters

Tags: php, urldecode

I have a search script where the user input some querywords that are sent with GET. If the user input contains special characters e.g. `äpple` the url becomes `search.php?q=äpple` and everything works fine. But if the user reruns this url `search.php?q=äpple` the browser address field shows `search.php?q=%E4pple`and the query fails. How should I decode that string. `urldecode`did not work. I thought this was exactly what it was for so is something else wrong? Or which other functions can I try?

UPDATE
if I use utf8_encode on the `search.php?q=%E4pple` it produces the right `ä`char but if the string in the url is sent by GET and thus correctly (and working) `ä`already, the utf8_encode messes it up.

I guess I can make a condition were I check the encoding before doing something but isnt it an easier way??

Comment: You shouldn't decode it ever, since php does that for you. Btw, what is your page encoding?

Comment: ok thanks, utf-8 and the regular questionmarkbox shows but everything else works. So you mean that if a user search with a specialchar query that shows as-it-is in the browser URL and the script is working, re-run the page with that same URL which now gets URL encoded by the browser (see question) should work since php should take care of the decoding?

Comment: browsers **always** send non-ascii chars as an escape sequence. So even if it is `ä` in the query string - browser sent it as a `%nnnn` anyway (you could check it by looking at your webserver access log)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by checking the encoding of $_GET['q'] and handle it appropriately for the result of the encode check. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php for functions that check encode.